# How to draw rectangles in a Table cell?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I have a table with a cell and want to place a horizontal bar chart in it. I want to paint this chart with rectangles in this cell to avoid another library.

Do I need a canvas to draw the rectangles? How to place the canvas in the cell and how to create the canvas on the right page (of the cell)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iText7 has two kinds of canvas objects:

A layout `Canvas`, a high-level object that acts as a bridge between high-and low-level operations that allows you to add high-level objects to a specified area. This canvas has no concept of a page.

A `PdfCanvas` that allows you to do low-level operations on either a specific page or form `XObject`, such as drawing lines, adding text at absolute positions, ...

The constructors of `Canvas` require either a form `XObject` or a `PdfCanvas`, so a page can be specified for `Canvas` this way.

Now, in order to draw rectangles into cells, I recommend implementing your own cell-event, and using PdfCanvas to draw the rectangles inside the event handling code.

Some useful links:
Tutorial part on event handlers (final example is the one you want): http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers

Drawing using pdfCanvas:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-2-adding-low-level-content